# Casting an object[] to another object[], is it possible?

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering if you can cast an object[] to another object[] of a different class.

Here's what I tried doing, but clearly it isn't working.

```
public CardCollection() {
    CardCollection[] myCollection = new CardCollection[MAX_CARDS];
    for(int i = 0; i < myCollection.length; i++){
        myCollection[i] = (BaseballCard[]) Collection[i];
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error when I tried casting the collection Object[] to BaseballCard.

I had previously made a

```
BaseBallCard[] Collection = new BaseBallCard[MAX_CARDS]; // MAX_CARDS=100;
```

I have tried myCollection[i]= (BaseballCard) Collection[i]. Gave me an error saying BaseballCard cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: What is `Collection` here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [casting Object array to Integer array error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115230/casting-object-array-to-integer-array-error)

Comment: You're not casting an object[] to another object[]. You're casting an object to an object[].

Comment: Have you tried `myCollection[i] = (BaseBallCard) Collection[i];`?

Comment: I'm casting an object to an object[]?? where

Comment: inside your loop: `myCollection[i] = (BaseballCard[])`

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing

```
 myCollection[i] = (BaseBallCard[]) Collection[i];
```

what you should do

```
 myCollection[i] = (BaseBallCard) Collection[i];
```

converting each object one by one

**Condition required**

You can cast to Object type and then again cast it to some different type of Object based on some conditions (like Object.getClass()). Means you should have same `Object1.getClass().getName()` and `Object2.getClass().getName()`

[Source1](http://www.coderanch.com/t/472455/java/java/cast-class-related-class) [Source2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256512/3841803)

Answer (score 1):

If BaseBallCard is a subclass of CardCollection, your code can be corrected as follows:

```
public CardCollection() {
    CardCollection[] myCollection = new CardCollection[MAX_CARDS];
    for(int i = 0; i < myCollection.length; i++){
        myCollection[i] = (BaseBallCard) Collection[i]; // note BaseBallCard not [i]
    }
}
```

Or more easily using [`Arrays.copyOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-U:A-int-java.lang.Class-):

```
public CardCollection() {
    CardCollection[] myCollection = Arrays.copyOf(Collection, MAX_CARDS, BaseBallCard.class);
}
```

But if BaseBallCard is a subclass of CardCollection, then every time you create a BaseBallCard, you'll implicitly call this constructor (since it is the default constructor for the parent type) and you'll wind up creating a new array of CardCollection every time you make a BaseBallCard. You don't really want that, believe me.

What you're probably trying to do, given the naming of the classes, is store a BaseBallCard[] in CardCollection.

```
public CardCollection() {
    BaseBallCard[] myCollection = new BaseBallCard[MAX_CARDS];
    // just create the array - don't try to populate it in the constructor
}
```

Then you could have separate methods for adding and removing a BaseBallCard from the CardCollection.

Comment: Oh. So all i had to do was extends CardCollection for BaseballCard class. nice. And as for the Arrays.copyof(). I can't use it. Apparently, the hw would be too easy if i did that. So we have to do everything manually. Professors and their limitations. QQ.. But that fixes everything. O_O

Comment: Please read the second half of my answer; you almost certainly *don't* want to make BaseBallCard extend CardCollection and use the code from your question.

Comment: I did make a object[] of type BaseBallCard, whenever i try to use a method in the CardCollection Class, it wouldn't work. ,

 }

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, you can achieve what you want as this:

```
public CardCollection() {
    CardCollection[] myCollection = new CardCollection[MAX_CARDS];
    for (int i = 0; i < myCollection.length; i++){
        myCollection[i] = (BaseBallCard) Collection[i];
    }
}
```

You might even skip the explicite cast, as `Collection` is a `BaseBallCard[]`.

Comment: I did that at first, but it gave me an error for BaseballCard, says cannot be resolved to a type. So i tried casting it as BaseballCard[]. :/

Comment: Yes, because the second `B` is *capital*!

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from BaseballCard to CardCollection. It's telling me to cast it as CardCollection